# Scrape ASIN on amazon webpage product

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

First, sorry for my poor english.
Actually, i make a script who find data on amazon webpage. I need to scrape asin on amazon webpage, with python and selenium.
I've made this code for to scrape asin:

```
    firstResult = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[data-index="1"]>div')
    asin = firstResult.get_attribute('data-asin')
```

But its not work, i have some errors on results:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div[data-index="1"]>div"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=96.0.4664.45)
```

The part of source code who has asin number, on webpage (ASIN is highlighted):
[image: ASIN highlighted in this screen]

Anyone know how to make for to scrape this ASIN in python with selenium please?
Ty for help!

Comment: What url is this?

Comment: Actually, its this URL: https://www.amazon.fr/PlayStation-%C3%89dition-Standard-DualSense-Couleur/dp/B08H93ZRK9, but its only for test. I want to scrap any ASIN on any amazon webpage. I think its same part of Source code on all amz webpages product @Arundeep Chohan

Comment: Try using this (//span[contains(.,'ASIN')])[1]//span[2] or //span[@class='a-list-item' and contains (.,'ASIN')]//span[2] as an xpath and then .text it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wait and look for the span which is located beside that tag.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
driver.get('https://www.amazon.fr/PlayStation-%C3%89dition-Standard-DualSense-Couleur/dp/B08H93ZRK9')
elem=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH," //span[@class='a-list-item' and contains (.,'ASIN')]//span[2]")))
print(elem.text)
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Outputs:

```
B08H93ZRK9
```

Another thing is that url actually has the same value at the end.
Which could be obtained which a simple string manipulation of the driver.current_url,

https://www.amazon.fr/PlayStation-%C3%89dition-Standard-DualSense-Couleur/dp/ **B08H93ZRK9**

Comment: Sorry for reply delay. Thanks for help, Im a beginner in python and selenium, sometime, i need help. all work now! Bye